# How to install Vim 8.1 Silently on Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, installing

I am trying to install gvim81.exe on multiple computers. The /s switch isn't working and /? doesn't give any results. Does anyone know how to silently install this version?

Comment: Do you need official build? If not, check https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/blob/master/bucket/vim.json what scoop uses to provide lates vim for windows

Comment: And it looks like they use official vim github repo :)

Comment: According to https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/issues/49, the /S switch should work for the `...mui.exe` installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider to use a gvim msi package, e.g. from https://github.com/petrkle/vim-msi/releases.

`msiexec` supports a wide variety command line options. `/passive` seams to be one you are looking for (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/standard-installer-command-line-options).

Example: `msiexec /package vim-8.1.55.msi /passive`

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the official Windows installer from the  site. It worked pretty well on 10+ Windows machines, across multiple years (5+). They are the "best" in terms of the integration with Windows ==> when you right click on two files, there should be a `Diff with Vim` option.

- Download link: https://www.vim.org/download.php#pc
  [image]

To note, there are other popular Vim builds, like the one salchint has suggested. Here goes one more:

- [Cream's Windows installer for Vim without Cream](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/). You can find the link at the bottom of [the Cream download page](http://cream.sourceforge.net/download.html)

Lastly, I would **recommend** using [`scoop`](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop) to install Vim on Windows. I have just updated all my Vim-on-Windows installation on 4 of my Windows 10 machines this afternoon using the `scoop` method. Bring up a Powershell with Admin right, and issue the following commands:

```
    set-executionpolicy remotesigned -scope currentuser
    iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh')
    scoop install vim
```

In the end, you need to populate your home directory (`C:\users\<username>`) with one more file and one more folder:

- `~/_vimrc` file (or `.vimrc` file), which configures all aspects of Vim;
- `~/vimfiles` ==> on Windows, the `autoload` and `ftplugin` folders should go into this folder. (This should be the Unix equivalent of `~/.vim` folder.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to install vim via `scoop`:

```
scoop install vim
```

Comment: Does this answer the question about installing "silently"?